# How to pass object associated with message past outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following:

```
[inbound channel adapter] -> ... -> foo -> [outbound channel adapter] -> bar
```

How can I write my spring-integration app so that `foo` can an extra object that's not part of the message the `[outbound channel adapter]` is to consume, such that `bar` gets it?

My app basically receives messages from AWS SQS (using `spring-integration-aws`), does some filtering / transformations, then publishes a message to Apache Kafka (using `spring-integration-kafka`), and if and only if that succeeds, deletes the original message off the SQS queue.

For that reason, when I receive the SQS message, I want to hold onto the receipt handle / acknowledgement object, transform the rest of the message into the Kafka message to be published, and then if that succeeds, make use of that receipt handle / acknowledgement object to dequeue the original message.

So say I'm using this example code off the `spring-integration-kafka` docs:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toKafka", outputChannel = "result")
public MessageHandler handler() throws Exception {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler =
            new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
    handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression("someTopic"));
    handler.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression("someKey"));
    handler.setFailureChannel(failures());
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
    // set more properties
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
}
```

With the above, if I have a message `message` and some extra, unrelated info `extra`, what do I send to the `toKafka` channel such that `handler` will consume `message`, and if that was successful, the `result` channel will receive `extra`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outbound channel adapters don't produce output - they are one-way only and end the flow.

You can make `toKafka` a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and add a second service activator; by default, the second will only be called if the first is successful.

Comment: How does spring-integration know the order of the service activators? And how can it tell if `handler` was successful?

Comment: They will be invoked in the order they are defined but I usually prefer `setOrder()` (all standard message handlers implement `Orderable`) and they will be invoked in the right order. Success means no exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Also, how do I get the result of a message sent with the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`?

If you were manually sending with `KafkaProducer#send(ProducerRecord)`, you get back a `Future<ProducerRecord>`.

What's the equivalent of that in `spring-integration-kafka`? I've tried setting an output channel in the handler, but nothing's going to it.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers; it doesn't help the community when searching for questions/answers and ends up causing extended commentary, which is frowned up by the admins here. See `setSendSuccesChannel()` and `setSendFailureChannel()`. It used to be the output channel before we added gateways (which use the output channel for replies). We need to fix the documentation.